# Difference between Rust compile modes

Tags: intellij-idea, compilation, rust, clion, rust-cargo

I'm new to Rust.

As I used to code a lot in Jetbrains IDEs (of course with Ideavim), I decide to pick up a Jetbrains IDE for Rust too, be more specificly CLion(as I also have to write C++ sometimes). Here you can treat CLion like Intellij or Pycharm/Rubymine/Android-studio if you are not fammiliar with it, because afterall what really does the work is the Rust plugin powered by LLDB.

Today I encountered a very strange thing:

I have wrote a library in C, which works fine in a C++ project. In my new Rust project, I want to keep using it, as a dynamic library. It compiles well, but it behaves strange, like, sometimes the logging to std does not work, the file operation does not work, and something more.

After some more investigation, I found out my test cases will:

- Fail if I run through CLion/Intellij `Run selected configuration`
- Fail if I run through CLI `cargo test -- --nocapture`
- Pass if I run through CLI `cargo test --release -- --nocapture`
- Pass if I run through CLion/Intellij `Debug selected configuration`

Here Intellij `Debug` behaves like `cargo --release`, `Run` behaves like `cargo`(without `--release`), have no idea why.

You may suspect that that's because I wrote some build-type-depending codes, but at least it's not true in the Rust part. As to the C library, it already been compiled, I do not think different rust compile types will change something inside it.

I checked the Rust configuration in CLion, found no items concerns to build mode.

OK, that's the context, and here comes my questions:

- What's the difference between Intellij `Run selected configuration`/`Debug selected configuration` for Rust by default
- Why Intellij `Debug`/`Run` behaves opposing to `cargo --release`/`cargo`
- What may cause the different behaving between compile mode while I have no mode-depending codes in Rust.(no third party crates here)

Comment: In my experience when a behavior change like that it's because you do some undefined behavior, without [mcve] that reproduce your problem, it's gonna be impossible to answer you.

Comment: Yeah you are right, maybe I'm seeking for just information not accurate anwsers. Tha's why I did not post any codes here. @Stargateur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who encountered similar problems, well not only in Rust, but also other programming langues, I found the reason for the different behaivors:

**Dynamic library mess**

I name it like this, not sure if it is correct, but to describe that multiple versions of the same dynamic library lay in your computers different paths may cause strange problems like I've encountered.

If you are in a situation like this, use `ldd` to check the library dependancies.

And also, remember to cleanup all the caches.

Comment: That maybe fixed your problem but I doubt this would be useful to anyone in the future.

Comment: rarely @Stargateur

Comment: Can you give more information, for future readers? How would I know, by using `ldd`, whether I'm subject to "strange problems" or not?